Are there finite possible things, countably infinite possible things, or something else?
How many possible things are there?
For example, a red storybook, a bike rental company, a mutant, the actress Ana de Armas, the iPhone 7, an asteroid, etc., are things.
Some things exist, like Philosophy Stack Exchange.
Some things do not exist, like a mythical white single-horned horse. But they are conceivable.
Some things may never have been conceived of, or have not been conceived of by a certain person, but are conceivable. I prefer not to give an example, to drive the point home.
Some things are conceivable, yet impossible. A unicorn is impossible, because it must be mythical/magical, which, perhaps, by definition, is irreal; so any existing single-horned white horse is not the ‘unicorn’ I have in mind. (“The man who does not exist” cannot exist, by definition.)
The man who does not exist does not exist. To what extent is he conceivable, however? Perhaps, since we can conceive of impossible things, he is indeed conceivable, just not possible.
I think then perhaps we can differentiate between Meinongian existence as ‘conceivability’, versus actual existence. This distinction may be free from paradoxes, if we say that conceivability can be defined as “exists as an idea”. This allows us to get rid of the concept of “possibility”, since we can simply say, “something possible is something that can exist in a logically consistent world”, for example.
I’m not sure, but maybe this can lead to a well-defined hierarchy (except I expect there to be paradoxes like Russell’s and Richard’s, actually):
Perhaps, in some language, there are the possible utterances. This distinguishes coherence from incoherence.
Then, we have the logically consistent theories versus the inconsistent ones: this lets us collapse the difference between a paradox-in-terms, like a tall-short person, and some a posteriori impossibility, like that one cannot have a world in which one can transform water into gold, that does not logically violate facts about a world with our laws of physics.
If we split the question of the number of possible things into the number of coherent (conceivable) things, and the number of possible (coherent + consistent) things, one issue may be how we can claim that a thing is conceivable just because it is coherent in a language, because the language lacks meaning until it is understood to refer to things, and it is not clear to me if we can claim a language is coherent if it refers to an inconsistent, incoherent, or impossible world.
Does this mean the number of possible things is just a mathematical result of how many distinct, composite things are generable from a number of initial or primitive things?
If so: then how many first things are there in our world?
(Part of me wants to argue that in any reasonable depiction of a world, there are only finitely many possible things, or countably infinitely many, or, maybe, a totally transcendental concept of absolute-infinitely many, if we allow ourselves to include certain infinite concepts inside our world.)
However, the important part of the question is in our world, how many possible things there are.

Related: Are there infinitely many possible thoughts?

@JuliusHamilton In our world there are real things. In addition, there are things which are possible in our world. Which class do you mean by your post? - As you know there are sets with cardinality bigger than Aleph_0. Do you consider them relevant for your question?

It begs a narrowing of 'things', one of the broadest descriptions we have. If I have a thought about something that might or might not be 'real', and can remember that thought, it must have storage somewhere in my brain (rather than following the same train of thought to reach it). I might even have written it down. So that thought exists, and it is real, whether or not the premise of the thought is possible.

What is a thing, what is "possible" and what is "our" world? This question as it stands lacks a real context and lacks a clear motivation imo.

What do you mean by "countably infinite"?  You just start counting but never end?

@JuliusHamilton For each positive integer n, is it metaphysically possible for at least n electrons to exist?

@MichaelHall https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set

Question: Is a number a "possible thing?"

"Some things may never have been conceived of, but are conceivable." === George Carlin said, "It's easy to come up with a sentence that's never been said before, like, "Hey let's go down to the baseball field and beat up Hitler's wife!"

@user509184: are you presuming finite, or infinite, space?

You may care to look at this

There is a problem with the formulation of your question because (most of) the examples you mention pertain to the physical realm, you ask whether such things could be "countably infinite".  But the latter term refers to a particular mathematical concept which is not a description of the physical realm but rather part of a certain mathematical formalism with only tenuous relation to the physical realm.
So the formulation of the question involves a category error as it were.  Apart from the issue of countable infinity, physicists tell us that there are on the order of 1080 elementary particles in the universe, so on that account there could certainly be only finitely many things.

I'm amused that we have to wait for a professional mathematician to make this answer.

And I've changed some little latex formatting to «poor man's latex»

Yeah, but suppose there are ever smaller, more elementary, "particles". At one time scientists thought the atom was the smallest indivisible particle, and they found it, then they detected or invented neutrons, protons and electron "particles" and they found them. But then, they found and/or predicted even smaller "elementary particles". What's the next chapter? Is there one or more elementary particle? How do we know when the limit is found? And, most importantly, how do you define "the physical realm"?

@WeatherVane That the physical realms definition is nebulous at best the fundantal fact that the mathematical realm is a distinct one. The starting point of math. platonism is rhia assumption

I think the answer lies between 5, or 6, and uncountable infinity, for the following reasons.
A 'possible thing in our world' needs to be either instantiated, i.e. the thing itself must exist, or it must exist as a representation, i.e. a thought in a mind, a description on a piece of paper, or a row of bits in a computer. Otherwise, the qualifier 'in our world' doesn't make any sense.
So, if our world is finite, then the number of possible things in that world are also finite. The universe is large, crazy large, some say, and so combinatorial enumerations will churn out numbers that are going through the roof, off the charts, but they will still be finite.
Since we are talking about representations we must allow for radical skepticism and account for solipsism. If only the solipsist exists, then the number of possible things in our, or rather my, world are limited to my brain. Miller's law states that the number of objects that an average human can hold in short term memory is seven, plus or minus two.
This accounts for the lower bound number of 5, which I previously mentioned.
Or, if you count the solipsist as well, 6.
If the world is infinitely large, then the number of things is infinitely many. There will be room for an infinite number of Boltzmann brains that could each contain a representation of a possible thing. Take for example coloured teddy bears. Teddy bears can have an uncountable infinite number of colours where each colour can be represented by a real number that maps to the exact wavelength of that colour. This means that between any two colours (say blue and a slightly lighter shade of blue) there are still an infinite number of colours, even if the reals get arbitrarily close, because of the infinite digital expansion of a given real number and something something Dedekind Cut...
So there are uncountably much coloured teddy bears. I use 'much' because we use 'much' for uncoutable nouns and coloured teddy bears clearly are uncountable nouns.
The thing is, I am not sure if an infinitely large universe is countably infinite or uncountably infinite. So, even though we can conceive of uncountably much coloured teddy bears, I am not sure if they will fit in an infinitely large universe...
Though I am almost sure we can fit Ana de Armas in.
